# This QueryDict instance is immutable (Trying to manually set form data)

Tags: django

When I go to save. It will not allow me. I am trying to add details into the database through inputting the form manually. I am struggling to actually input the data into the form so I can save it.

For example, I have tried to get the form data then set the data I would like it to be set to however Im guessing this is incorrect? I cannot find a command to set the form data manually. Is this possible?

views

```
from telnetlib import LOGOUT
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from matplotlib import use
from matplotlib.pyplot import get
from matplotlib.style import context
from werkzeug import Request
from .models import Account, Question, sni, Option
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth import login as dj_login
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import AccountAuthenticationForm, SNIForm, createUserForm, resultForm


def question_detail(request, id ='default'):
    question = Question.objects.get(QuestionsID = id)
    options = Option.objects.filter(QuestionsID = question)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        current_user = request.user
        form = resultForm(request.POST)
        form.data['userID'] = current_user.userID
        form.data['QuestionsID'] = id
        optionID = request.POST.get('result')
        form.data['ChosenOptionID'] = optionID
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()


        messages.success(request, "Answer Submitted")
        return redirect('dashboardPage')

    context = {'question' : question,
                'options' : options}





    return render(request, 'questionForm.html', context)
```

html for the form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
        <style>
            body,
            html {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                background: #7abecc !important;
            }
            .user_card {
                width: 350px;
                margin-top: auto;
                margin-bottom: auto;
                background: #74cfbf;
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 10px;
                box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                border-radius: 5px;
    
            }
    
            .form_container {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
    
            #form-title{
                color: #fff;
                
            }

            #questionTitle {
                text-align: left;
            }
    
            .login_btn {
                width: 100%;
                background: #33ccff !important;
                color: white !important;
            }
            .login_btn:focus {
                box-shadow: none !important;
                outline: 0px !important;
            }
            .login_container {
                padding: 0 2rem;
            }
            .input-group-text {
                background: #f7ba5b !important;
                color: white !important;
                border: 0 !important;
                border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
            }
            .input_user,
            .input_pass:focus {
                box-shadow: none !important;
                outline: 0px !important;
            }
    
            #messages{
                background-color: grey;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }


        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="user_card">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    
    
                        <h3 id="form-title">Question Form</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <h6 id="questionTitle"> {{question.QuestionText}} </h6>
                            </div>

                            {% for option in options %}
                            <input type="radio" id="{{ option.OptionID }}" name="result" value="{{ option.OptionID }}">
                            <label for="{{ option.OptionID }}">{{ option.OptionText }}</label> <br>
                            {% endfor %}

    
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                                     <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                   </div>
                        </form>
    
                    </div>
                    {{form.errors}}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <p id='messages'>{{message}} </p>
                    {%  endfor  %}
            
                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Fix:

Views

```
def question_detail(request, id ='default'):
    question = Question.objects.get(QuestionsID = id)
    options = Option.objects.filter(QuestionsID = question)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':

        current_user = request.user
        c = current_user.userID
        acc = Account.objects.get(userID=c)
        OptionID = request.POST.get('result')
        op = Option.objects.get(OptionID = OptionID)

        if OptionID and c:
            obj = Result.objects.create(userID = acc, QuestionsID = question, ChosenOptionID = op)
            obj.save()



        messages.success(request, "Answer Submitted")
        return redirect('dashboardPage')

    context = {'question' : question,
                'options' : options}





    return render(request, 'questionForm.html', context)
```

I have saved it directly into the database through the model. I have not used the form function.

Comment: Not entirely sure yet what you are trying to achieve, but using data directly from the POST dictionary to make a query without cleaning it first is an SQL vulnerability.